# How to show a real valued function of several variables is analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, analyticity, analytic-functions, smooth-functions

Let $f:\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$ be a given function. In general, how can I show that $f$ is smooth (infinitely differentiable) and analytic. I know this is a bit vaguely stated question, but I just need a general idea about showing smoothness and analyticity.

If you can give me some examples that would be great. PDF's and other sources are also welcome.

Comment: How does $f$ arise?  Is it given by a closed-form formula, as an integral, a solution of a PDE, ???

Comment: Closed-form formulas are generally analytic except where they run into a problem (poles, branch points etc).  In particular the sum or product of analytic functions is analytic; the quotient is analytic as long as the denominator is nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to

- guess what the power series development of $f$ is,
- show that the function $g$ defined via this development is indeed analytic (converges on a non-trivial domain),
- show that $g$ shares enough properties with $f$ that they are the same function (e.g. both are solutions to a differential equation with boundary conditions).